# Python "list index out of range" error in list iteration

Tags: python

What am I doing Wrong?
"list index out of range" on line 7
Sorry for russian letters in code, it's my hometask.
Help me please.

```
import sys
morze = ['-----', '.----', '..---', '...--', '....-', '.....', '-....', '--...', '---..', '----.']
ralphabet = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя' #Russian alphabet 0-32
doc = "Вот цитата для тебя : Встретив двусмысленность , отбрось искушение угадать . С наилучшими пожеланиями , Андрей ." #doc = open('text.txt') 
print('Не поддерживается правильное отображение знаков препинания. Ставьте знаки через пробел.') #Attention
for line in doc:
    line = line.lower() #Downcase
    for word in line.split(' '):
        ln = len(word) #Length of word
        if ln == 1 and word in ralphabet: #One-letter words
            letternumber = ralphabet.find(word)
            sys.stdout.write(morze[letternumber] + ' ')
        elif ln == 1: #Symbols
            ...
        elif ln != 1 and not (word[0] in alphabet): #Symbols error
            sys.stdout.write('[ERROR]')
        elif ln != 1: #Long words
            shift = ln - 1
            if shift > 10:
                shift = 10
            for letter in word:
                letternumber = ralphabet.find(letter) + 1 - shift
                for digit in str(letternumber):
                    sys.stdout.write(morze[digit] + ' ')
            sys.stdout.write('| ')
        sys.stdout.write('| ')

input() #PAUSE
```

Comment: Which is line 7? Please include the complete error message.

Comment: Please post full traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the index of the word to find something in the morze list if you `print(letternumber,len(morze))` you can see exactly why you get the error:

```
  (31, 10)
   ^    ^
```

The length of `ralphabet` is `66` and the length of morze is `10` so that is not going to work.

You might also want to change these two lines:

```
 elif ln > 1 and word[0] not in alphabet:  #Symbols error
            sys.stdout.write('[ERROR]')
 elif ln > 1:  #Long words
```

`0` is also != 1 but `word[0]` is not going to work .

You are also calling `str` on  `letternumber` then trying to pass a string as an index:

```
       for digit in str(letternumber):
             sys.stdout.write(morze[digit] + ' ')
                                       ^
                                       string = error
```

You could use:

```
  for digit in range(letternumber):
         sys.stdout.write(morze[digit] + ' ')
```

But again if  `letternumber = ralphabet.find(letter) + 1 - shift` is greater than 10 you would get an error.

Comment: `for digit in str(letternumber):
sys.stdout.write(morze[digit] + ' ')`

Comment: @ftvkyo2011, is that a question?

Comment: This is not a question.